# Installing Headers DESTINATION ERROR

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am using a ROS metapackage system to install certain header files to the include directory under `catkin_ws/devel`.
My `CMakeLists.txt` is as follows:

```
          install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}
                  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
                  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
                  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)
```

I amsimply following the enumeration here: http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html
For some reason, I keep hitting the brick as in :

```
                     CMake Error at gocator_bridge/CMakeLists.txt:15 (install):
                                              install DIRECTORY given no DESTINATION!
```

Could I be missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229544/installing-headers-destination-error/) by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Could I be missing something?

Metapackages are not meant to do anything but gather `run_depend`s (from [wiki/catkin/package.xml - Format 1 (Legacy) - Metapackages](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml#Metapackages-1)):

> It is often convenient to group multiple packages as a single logical package. This can be accomplished through **metapackages**.

This is speculation, but you're probably getting that error because `CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION` is not defined for metapackages.

See [catkin metapackage now requires CMakeLists.txt?](http://answers.ros.org/question/59648/catkin-metapackage-now-requires-cmakeliststxt/) and [wiki/catkin/package.xml - Format 1 (Legacy) - Metapackages](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml#Metapackages-1) for some more info.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2016-03-19**:
Thank you indeed for the references. I had to set my `DESTINATION` to one of the packages within the metapackages' include directory to work around this.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-19**:
Just to be sure, not the part where you're **not supposed to install anything** with metapackages.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-19**:
Also:

> [..] within the metapackages' include directory [..]

? Metapackages are empty. How can it have an include directory?

**Comment by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on 2016-03-19**:
I chose the include directory of one of the sub packages within the meta-package as the installation destination. Is this clearer?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-19**:
It's all up to you obviously. As long as "*within the meta-package*" does not actually mean that you are storing packages *inside* the directory of the metapackage. Also, your comment could still be understood as the metapackage installing headers, and that is not something you shoul do.